# Php rename files using js file that contains names

Tags: php

Is it possible to use php to rename files in directory to match the output of a js file created. I have thousands of images downloaded from an API i was using , but switched my app to a new API and had to match up the old imageID with the new imageID. I'd rather batch rename the files instead of having the js file loaded to get the new id names. I have little experience in php and all the tutorials were simple file rename and nothing more complex like this.

img.js

```
var img_ar = {
"pid_12685":"2578377",
"pid_12757":"2980444",
"pid_12916":"3056906"
}
```

Current image file names /images

```
2578377.png
2980444.png
3056906.png
```

Desired file names after running php script

```
pid_12685.png  (old file name 2578377.png)
pid_12757.png  (old file name 2980444.png)
pid_12916.png  (old file name 3056906.png)
```

Comment: Remove `var img_ar =` and then use `json_decode($contents, true)` to convert it to an associative array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can make a php script (not necessary in your web server) and then call it by `php your_script.php`

in that script you can use [scandir](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.scandir.php) to get an array of all the images in your images directory

then you  have to loop through that array and use the [rename](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.rename.php) function to rename images

---

since i don't see a relation between old name number and the new name number
you can create an array

```
$names = [
    '2578377.png' => 'pid_12685.png'
    '2980444.png' => 'pid_12757.png'
    '3056906.png' => 'pid_12916.png'
];
```

then, in your loop do `rename($imageName, $names[$imageName]);`

---

you can use this script:

1. either put the script in your images directory, or change the $path variable so the script will use the right directory
2. change $names to include all your images

   ```
   <?php
   $path = '.';
   $files = array_diff(scandir($path), ['.', '..']);

   $names = [
       '2578377.png' => 'pid_12685.png',
       '2980444.png' => 'pid_12757.png',
       '3056906.png' => 'pid_12916.png'
   ];

   foreach($files as $file){
       if(is_file($file) && isset($names[$file])){
           rename($file, $names[$file]);
       }
   }
   ```
3. call the script by `php script_name.php`